# How to move a value in a list one element to the right every time the key "D' is pressed using Python and without any imports?

Tags: python

So I have a list and I am wondering if there is a way to move the element to the right by pressing D and change the moved element?

For example

```
list=[ 0, **, **, **]
```

When I press D, I want the list to end up something like this.

```
list= [--, 0, **, **]
```

And the next time I press D,

```
list=[--,--,0, **]
```

Comment: would the elements wrap around? or would new elements be generated to the left?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without importing a module that lets you listen to keyboard events (e.g. `keyboard`).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to do what you requested (without completely understanding how you plan on rotating the elements [single element or wrap entire list])

```
temp_list = [ 0, 1, 2, 3]

def rotate_entire_list(temp_list):
    new_list = [temp_list[-1]]
    new_list.extend(temp_list[:-1])
    return new_list

def rotate_element_in_list(temp_list, element_pos):
    if element_pos == len(temp_list) - 1:
        temp_list[0], temp_list[-1] = temp_list[-1], temp_list[0]
    else:
        temp_list[element_pos], temp_list[element_pos + 1] = temp_list[element_pos + 1], temp_list[element_pos]
    return temp_list
    
start_index = 0
while(input('press D to rotate') == 'D'):
    print(rotate_element_in_list(temp_list, 0))
    start_index += 1
    # or
    #print(rotate_entire_list(temp_list))
```

This does require inputting the letter 'D' to function -- unsure if this is an acceptable usage of the D input (if input is allowed?).